# Listing S3 folders via Java API, excluding files

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an AWS S3 bucket with several folders, subfolders, and files. I want to get a list of all subfolders of a folder, excluding files. I think I understand that the S3 key concept makes such distinctions iffy, but the AWS web gui allows users to create folders without files.

The [listObject()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method defined in com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 returns an ObjectListing with a list of [S3ObjectSummary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html) for the actual files. Knowing the delimiter, it would be possible to split the keys into a folder hierarchy and filenames, but this appears complicated and error-prone.

Is there an API to get a list of folders without parsing the key property of S3ObjectSummary?

Answer (score 0):

'Objects' in S3 (ie files) do not exist on S3 in actual folders - the 'Keys' for those objects are all at the same level of the hierarchy, and contain slashes which are then displayed to the user on the console *as if* they were in folders. To find only the 'folders' as opposed to the files, you will need to work out for each object in the bucket whether there are any other files with the same key but with a slash (`/`) and then more characters. So eg if you had objects with keys like:

```
a
b
b/c
b/c/d1
b/c/d2
```

you would only know `c` is a folder because there are other objects 'inside' it (ie with extra characters after the slash.

Comment: I would have hoped for an API to handle this for me. Parsing strings is always a possibility, but I can't believe I'm the first to need this ...